# How do I display the appropriate field in a simple form collection select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

In a Rails 3.2 app with bootstrap and simple form, I have the following in a view:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@invoice) do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :user_id, :collection => @users %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

Instead of displaying username the pull down menu displays records like so:

```
#<User:0X007...>
```

I haven't found any simple form syntax that will display the username.

Comment: Does SimpleForm generate a Twitter Bootstrap autocomplete field or something when you do `f.input` with an array for a second argument?

Comment: As a wild guess, I might try `:collection => @users.map(&:name)` assuming your `User` model has a `name` attribute) instead of what you have.

Comment: Thanks, Jason. See update to the question.

Comment: Interesting. `@users` is evidently `nil` for some reason. Your task now, I think, is to make that not be the case.

Comment: Jason, separate problem. I'll post another question on that. If you put your solution in as an answer, I'll select it as the correct answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Feel free to link to your other question here and I can take a crack at it.

Comment: there was an error and thus the app was rendering the action "new". i did a redirect_to "new" to renew the @users array. The error is related to accepts_nested_attributes_for. I'll provide a link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might use `#map` to grab one certain user attribute.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@invoice) do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :user_id, :collection => @users.map(&:name) %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your model does have a "name" attribute, then @users will work to show names and store ids. However, if your model has another attribute instead of "name", for example "full_name", then all you have to do is:

```
@users.map{|u| [u.full_name, u.id]}
```